# Putting a thread to sleep for decimal value

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, decimal

This question is about `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int)`. I know there is no method for a decimal value, but I really need to work with decimals.

I have a device which takes 20.37 milliseconds to turn by 1 degree. So, I need to put the code to sleep for an appropriate multiplication of 20.37 (2 degrees = 20.37*2 etc). Since the thread class got no decimal sleep method, how can I do this?

Comment: Thread.Sleep() only guarantees to sleep for _at least_ that number of milliseconds, that means you could request 20ms and as well end up with 800ms before your thread is restarted. If you want real time, that API is probably not for you.

Comment: Does your device API provide any notifications such as `OnTurned`?

Comment: Why do you need it THAT accurate?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: Hi, the case is the system is a module for a highly critical system :)

Comment: @Knight You probably want something more accurate than Thread.Sleep, then.

Comment: @oleksii: Hi, there is no API. I'm accessing it by jumping into it's own driver dll.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: My goodness, if I use 20 as the value, instead of 20.37 that can be dangerous. Device can turn only 270 degrees so 0.37*270 means I am gonna miss 99.9 degrees!!!

Comment: @Knight Are you sure the driver has no APIs that could make the device handle the timing itself? Even if you code natively in C++, I can't see any way to guarantee anything approaching microsecond accuracy from user space.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yes, it has no API. The rotation can be stopped by sending the interruption signal (byte array). The DLL is C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does not work that way. `Sleep` will grant you that the thread sats idle for x time, but not that it won't stay idle for more. The end of the sleep period means that the thread is available for the scheduler to run it, but the scheduler may chose to run other threads/processes at that moment.

Get the initial instant, find the final instant, and calculate the current turn by the time passed. Also, do not forget to check how precise the time functions are.

Real-time programming has some particularities in its own as to advice you to seek for more info in the topic before trying to get something to work. It can be pretty extensive (multiprocessing OS vs monoprocessing, priorities, etc.)

Comment: Time functions are precise to 15ms (at least `DateTime.Now` is...)

Comment: Pleas read my comments in the question. You might be able to provide me a better answer :)

Comment: There is no better answer. You cannot mount a good real time system (note that I did not say "program") if you ignore real time programming issues. Any sane device should provide you, incorporated in its hardware, a set of primitives for handling it correctly ("rotate x degrees", "rotate y degrees"). At the very least, a minimal feedback ("my current position is "). If it does not, you are up for all the RT gore (what happens if the user crushes the CPU because he is also ripping DVDs, and there is no time for your process?, and all of the other "funny" possibilities).

Comment: I think if he's concerned about .37ms it's going to be a dedicated machine.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance or a virus, or the antivirus, or the scheduler switching processes, or defrag, or whatever. Someone should check Windows and C# EULAs and check what they tell about Real Time Systems...

Comment: @SJuan76 If they have a virus in a RT system, they have bigger problems than the timing being off ;)

Comment: OK, I am moving with 20ms. I am sure the way windows do threading is not 100% correct, because I managed to rotate the device by 270 (or something simmilar)degrees by 20*270. I didn't miss much degrees by missing 0.37*270

Answer (score 0):

Right, as pointed out in the comments, `Thread.Sleep` isn't 100% accurate. However, you can get it to (in theory) wait for 20.27 milliseconds by converting the milliseconds to ticks, and then making a new `TimeSpan` and calling the method with it, as follows:

```
Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(202700)) 
//202700 is 20.27 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond (which is 10,000)
```

Again, this is probably not going to be 100% accurate (as Thread.Sleep only guarantees for AT LEAST that amount of time). But if that's accurate enough, it'll be fine.

Comment: @Knight Just about to ask that. I made it **abundantly** clear that it wasn't perfect... So if the downvoter isn't just a rage-voter, I'd like an explanation please!

Comment: It weren't I that downvoted... but... I want to point out that the implementation of `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)` just uses `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` cast to an integral value, so it is not possible to get sub-millisecond accuracy with this.

Comment: @MatthewWatson You're right there... unfortunately. So this is useless compared to just using `Thread.Sleep(20)`...

Answer (score -1):

You can simply divide the integer - I just figured that out.

I needed less than a milisecond of time the thread sleeps so I just divided that time by an integer, you can either define a constant or just type in:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(time / 100);
```

Or what number you want.
Alternatively, as mentioned, you can do it like:

```
int thisIsTheNumberYouDivideTheTimeBy = 100;
Thread.Sleep(time / thisIsTheNumberYouDivideTheTimeBy);
```

Its actually quite simple. Hope that helped.

By the way, instead of

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
```

you can just type

```
Thread.Sleep(x);
```

unless you haven't written

```
using System.Threading;
```

in the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. But as a work around,  i substitute the float vslie but convert to int value in the passing. The code itself rounds off for me and the thread sleeps for that long. As i said, its a work around and i'm just saying, not that it's accurate

Answer (score -3):

You can use little bit of math as a workaround.
Let´s assume, that you don´t want to be extremely precise, 
but still need overall float precise sleep.

`Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(20,21));`
This should give you ~20.5 sleep timing. Use your imagination now.

TotalSleeps / tries = "should be wanted value", but for single sleep interval, this will not be true.

Dont use new Random() make an instance before.

Comment: First off, this answer is wrong; your conclusion that this "should" give you certain timing on average is incorrect; whether it *should* do anything is irrelevant; what is relevant is what it *does* do, and Sleep will not necessarily be observed to have that behaviour. Second, the question requires *precise realtime timings*; no usage of Sleep is appropriate for that. **Windows is not a realtime operating system**. Third, **please do not waste your time and that of others posting wrong answers to five-year-old questions that have an accepted answer.**